# Xamarin Forms datagrid does not show related data

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to setup the following.  A listview that shows a list of daily surgery cases.  When a case is clicked it navigates to a content page containing the details for the case as well as a linked datagrid that contains all of the procedures for the case.  I am able to see the listview and navigate to the case detail.  The problem is that the procedures do not populate the datagrid using the sxCaseId.  How do I get the datagrid to show the related procedures.

**SxCaseDetailsView**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:utility="clr-namespace:QiXApp.Utility;assembly=QiXApp"
             xmlns:renderers="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms.Renderers;assembly=Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms"
             xmlns:xForms="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="QiXApp.Views.SxCaseDetailsView"
             utility:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
             Title="SxCaseDetailsView New New New"
             x:Name="SxCaseDetails">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Case Details" />
                <StackLayout Padding="10">
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Padding="10" x:Name="MasterGrid">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>

                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>

                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Text="CaseId" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding SelectedSxCase.SxCaseId}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <Label Text="Dos" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <renderers:SfDatePicker x:Name="dos" BindingContext="{Binding SelectedSxCase.Dos}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                        <Label Text="Eye" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
                        <Picker x:Name="EyePicker" ItemsSource="{Binding Eyes, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Eye1, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSxCase.EyeId, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedSxCase.EyeId, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                        <Label Text="Facesheet" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"/>
                        <Entry Text="{Binding SelectedSxCase.Facesheet, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"/>
                        <Label Text="Record" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4"/>
                        <Entry Text="{Binding SelectedSxCase.Record, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"/>
                        <Label Text="Complication" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5"/>
                        <Switch IsToggled="{Binding SelectedSxCase.Complication, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"/>
                        <Label Text="ReturnOr" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6"/>
                        <Switch IsToggled="{Binding SelectedSxCase.ReturnOr, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6"/>
                        <Label Text="Physician" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7"/>
                        <Picker x:Name="PhysicianPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding Physicians, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Physician1, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSxCase.PhysicianId, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedSxCase.PhysicianId, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7"/>

                        <Button Text="Update Case" Style="{StaticResource RegularButton}"
                                    Command="{Binding UpdateSxCaseCommand}" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Button Text="Delete Case" Style="{StaticResource RegularButton}" 
                                    Command="{Binding DeleteSxCaseCommand}" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Button Text="Procedures" Style="{StaticResource RegularButton}"
                                Command="{Binding OnOpenSxCaseProceduresJoinCommand}" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>



                    </Grid>

                </StackLayout>

                <xForms:SfDataGrid 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding SxCaseProcedureJoins}">
                </xForms:SfDataGrid>


            </StackLayout>

        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**SxCaseDetailsViewModel**

```
  namespace QiXApp.ViewModels
{

public class SxCaseDetailsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ISxCaseDataService _sxCaseDataService;
    private ISxCaseProcedureJoinDataService _sxCaseProcedureJoinDataService;
    private IEyeDataService _eyeDataService;
    private IPhysicianDataService _physicianDataService;

        private SxCase _selectedSxCase;
        private readonly IGenericRepository _genericRepository;



        private ObservableCollection<SxCase> _sxCases;
        private ObservableCollection<SxCaseProcedureJoin> _sxCaseProcedureJoins;


        private List<Eye> _eyes;
        private Eye _selectedEye;
        private List<Physician> _physicians;
        private Physician _selectedPhysician;




        public SxCaseDetailsViewModel(IConnectionService connectionService,
            INavigationService navigationService, IDialogService dialogService,
            ISxCaseProcedureJoinDataService sxCaseProcedureJoinDataService,
            IEyeDataService eyeDataService, IPhysicianDataService physicianDataService,
            ISxCaseDataService sxCaseDataService, IEnumerable<SxCaseProcedureJoin> sxCaseId) : base(connectionService, navigationService, dialogService)
        {
            _sxCaseDataService = sxCaseDataService;
            _sxCaseProcedureJoinDataService = sxCaseProcedureJoinDataService;
            _eyeDataService = eyeDataService;
            _physicianDataService = physicianDataService;

            SxCases = new ObservableCollection<SxCase>();
            SxCaseProcedureJoins = new ObservableCollection<SxCaseProcedureJoin>(sxCaseId);





            GetEyes();
            GetPhysicians();



        }


        public ICommand UpdateSxCaseCommand => new Command(OnUpdateSxCase);

        public SxCase SelectedSxCase
        {
            get => _selectedSxCase;
            set
            {
                _selectedSxCase = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<SxCase> SxCases
        {
            get => _sxCases;
            set
            {
                _sxCases = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<SxCaseProcedureJoin> SxCaseProcedureJoins
        {
            get => _sxCaseProcedureJoins;
            set
            {
                _sxCaseProcedureJoins = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }




        public List<Eye> Eyes
        {
            get => _eyes;
            set
            {
                _eyes = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }

        }

        private async Task GetEyes()
        {

            Eyes = await _eyeDataService.GetEyeListAsync();
        }





        public List<Physician> Physicians
        {
            get => _physicians;
            set
            {
                _physicians = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private async Task GetPhysicians()
        {
            Physicians = await _physicianDataService.GetPhysicianListAsync();
        }

        //private async Task GetSxCaseProcedureJoins(int sxCaseId)
        //{
        //    SxCaseProcedureJoins =
        //        (ObservableCollection<SxCaseProcedureJoin>) await _sxCaseProcedureJoinDataService.GetAllSxCaseProcedureJoinsForSxCaseAsync(sxCaseId);
        //}



        public override async Task InitializeAsync(object data)
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            SxCases = (await _sxCaseDataService.GetAllSxCasesAsync()).ToObservableCollection();

            SelectedSxCase = (SxCase)data;

            IsBusy = false;
        }

        public async Task<SxCaseProcedureJoin> GetSxCaseProcedureJoins(int sxCaseId)
        {
            UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(ApiConstants.BaseApiUrl)
            {
                Path = $"{ApiConstants.SxCaseProcedureJoinsForSxCaseEndpoint}/{sxCaseId}"
            };

            var sxCaseProcedureJoins = await _genericRepository.GetAsync<SxCaseProcedureJoin>(builder.ToString());

            return sxCaseProcedureJoins;
        }





        private async void OnUpdateSxCase(object sxCase)
        {
            await _sxCaseDataService.UpdateSxCase(SelectedSxCase.SxCaseId, SelectedSxCase);
            OnPropertyChanged();
            await _dialogService.ShowDialog("Case details updated.", "Success", "OK");
            await _navigationService.NavigateToAsync<SxCaseViewModel>();
            //await _navigationService.PopToRootAsync();

        }

        public ICommand DeleteSxCaseCommand => new Command(async () =>
        {
            await _sxCaseDataService.DeleteSxCase(SelectedSxCase.SxCaseId);
            await _dialogService.ShowDialog("Case deleted.", "Success", "OK");
            await _navigationService.NavigateToAsync<SxCaseViewModel>();

        });


    }


}
```

**SxCaseDataService**

```
 namespace QiXApp.Services.Data
{


    public class SxCaseDataService : BaseService, ISxCaseDataService
    {
        HttpClient _client;
        public List<SxCase> SxCases { get; private set; }
        public List<SxCase> SelectedSxCase { get; private set; }
        private readonly IGenericRepository _genericRepository;
        public List<Eye> Eyes { get; set; }





        public SxCaseDataService(IGenericRepository genericRepository, ISxCaseProcedureJoinDataService sxCaseProcedureJoinDataService,
            IBlobCache cache = null) : base(cache)
        {
            _genericRepository = genericRepository;
            _client = new HttpClient();


        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Eye>> GetEyesAsync()
        {
            UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(ApiConstants.BaseApiUrl)
            {
                Path = ApiConstants.EyeEndpoint
            };

            var eyes = await _genericRepository.GetAsync<List<Eye>>(builder.ToString());



            return eyes;

        }


        public async Task<IEnumerable<SxCase>> GetAllSxCasesAsync()
        {
            UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(ApiConstants.BaseApiUrl)
            {
                Path = ApiConstants.SxCaseEndpoint
            };

            var sxCases = await _genericRepository.GetAsync<List<SxCase>>(builder.ToString());



            return sxCases;

        }



        public async Task UpdateSxCase(int sxCaseId, SxCase selectedSxCase)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectedSxCase);

            StringContent content = new StringContent(json);

            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(ApiConstants.BaseApiUrl)
            {

                Path = ApiConstants.SxCaseEndpoint
            };

            var result = await httpClient.PutAsync(builder.ToString() + sxCaseId, content);
            //var result = await httpClient.PutAsync(Url + sxCaseId, content);
        }

        public async Task<SxCase> AddSxCase(SxCase sxCase)
        {
            UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(ApiConstants.BaseApiUrl)
            {
                Path = ApiConstants.SxCaseAddEndpoint
            };

            var result = await _genericRepository.PostAsync(builder.ToString(), sxCase);

            return result;
        }

        public async Task DeleteSxCase(int sxCaseId)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(ApiConstants.BaseApiUrl)
            {

                Path = ApiConstants.SxCaseDeleteEndpoint
            };

            var result = await httpClient.DeleteAsync(builder.ToString() + sxCaseId);

        }


    }
}
```

**SxCaseProcedureJoinDataService**

```
 namespace QiXApp.Services
{
    public class SxCaseProcedureJoinDataService : BaseService, ISxCaseProcedureJoinDataService
    {
        HttpClient _client;

        public List<SxCaseProcedureJoin> SelectedSxCaseProcedureJoin { get; private set; }
        public List<SxCase> SelectedSxCase { get; private set; }

        private readonly IGenericRepository _genericRepository;

        public IEnumerable<SxCaseProcedureJoin> SxCaseProcedureJoins { get; set; }

        public SxCaseProcedureJoinDataService(IGenericRepository genericRepository,
            IBlobCache cache = null) : base(cache)
        {
            _genericRepository = genericRepository;
            _client = new HttpClient();



        }


        public async Task<IEnumerable<SxCaseProcedureJoin>> GetAllSxCaseProcedureJoinsForSxCaseAsync(int sxCaseId)
        {
            UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(ApiConstants.BaseApiUrl)
            {
                Path = $"{ApiConstants.SxCaseProcedureJoinsForSxCaseEndpoint}/{sxCaseId}"
            };

            var sxCaseProcedureJoins = await _genericRepository.GetAsync<IEnumerable<SxCaseProcedureJoin>>(builder.ToString());
            return sxCaseProcedureJoins;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: does `SxCaseProcedureJoins` contain data?  Have you actually verified this in the debugger?

Comment: when you navigate to detail page,have you set the `BindingContext` to the page ?

Comment: There is data in the SxCaseProcedureJoins. I can see the data in the API endpoint, I just can see it in the App. If I run the app with SxCases, Eyes, or Physicians in the datagrid I can see that data. I just can see the SxCaseProcedureJoins using the SxCaseId that exists in both SxCases and SxCaseProcedureJoins. I am using a ViewModelLocater so I'm not using a BindingContext. @Jason

Comment: I'd suggest manually setting the grid's ItemSource in the code behind after you load the data.  That should help you determine if the problem is with the grid or with the data binding